# What rules govern the copying of variables in Javascript closures?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'd just like to check my understanding of variable copying in Javascript. From what I gather, variables are passed/assigned by reference unless you explicitly tell them to create a copy with the `new` operator. But I'm a little uncertain when it comes to using closures. Say I have the following code:

```
var myArray = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20];
var fnlist = [];
for (var i in myArray) {
    var data = myArray[i];
    fnlist.push(function() {
        var x = data;
        console.log(x);
    });
}
fnlist[2](); // returns 20
```

I gather that this is because `fnlist[2]` only looks up the value of `data` at the point where it is invoked. So I tried an alternative tack:

```
var myArray = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20];
var fnlist = [];
for (var i in myArray) {
    var data = myArray[i];
    fnlist.push(function() {
        var x = data;
        return function() {
            console.log(x);         
        }
    }());
}
fnlist[2](); // returns 10
```

So now it returns the 'correct' value. Am I right to say that it works because a function resolves all variable references to their 'constant' values when it is invoked? Or is there a better way to explain it?

Any explanations / links to explanations regarding this referencing / copying business would be appreciated as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Closure variables are bound ("saved" in the closure) at the moment when its scope ends, that is, when you leave the function where the closure is defined:

```
function make_closure() {
   var x = 10;
   var closure = function() { alert(x) }
   x = 20
   return closure;
}

func = make_closure()
func() // what do you think?
```

The solution you've found is perfectly correct - you introduce yet another scope and force closure to bind variables in that "inner" scope.

See [here](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html) for details and explanations.

Comment: That's not really accurate. There's no real "saving" going on, and no copying.  that function created inside "make_closure" were to be called before the statement that sets "x" to 20, it's show "10" in the alert.